# Timeseries monthly mean - want to plot mean at the middle of the month; currently at the end

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRa4v.png)I have a dataframe with index changed to hourly timestamps. I am trying to plot daily mean and monthly mean using the resample function. The problem - the monthly mean values are showing at the end of the month, however, need to placed at the middle of the month in the plot. 
Also, I don't understand clearly if monthly mean is generated as a new series within the same dataframe or how are the new monthly mean values stored in the original dataframe. 
Any help will be appreciated. 
I am attaching a screenshot of how the new series (or so I assume) of monthly means looks like...it automatically comes with a Date column/index.
Not allowed to post pictures, being new to Stack...trying to do with copying how monthly mean appears here:

> Blockquote
>   Blockquote

```
Date
2018-01-31    223.904054
2018-02-28    121.776614
2018-03-31     82.700000
2018-04-30     72.744382
2018-05-31     71.933148
2018-06-30     70.282517
2018-07-31     38.752420
2018-08-31     34.008562
2018-09-30     41.324649
2018-10-31    113.053371
\\\
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esG1z.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate you dataframe by start of month with `MS` and then adjust the period through the `loffset` parameter. Below you can see an example (resampling to beginning of month and then offsetting it by 14 days):

```
df = df.resample('MS', loffset=pd.Timedelta(14, 'd')).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you Jose! I also found a way with index.shift(-15).